# android gradle exclude specific buildType from command line

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my build.gradle file i've created three build types debug relese and internal.
I'm running "gradlew assemble" from the command line.
i want to have the option not to build my 'internal' buildType.
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following command:

```
assemble{BuildType}
```

in your case

```
gradlew assembleInternal
```

Will Help. It will trigger build with Buildtype Internal.

More info: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types

Comment: You are right , i can run "gradlew assembleDebug assembleRelease". Is there a way to run a single customized command or to use excude(-x)

Comment: @Jonny can you please elaborate more on customized command. I cannot understand your requirement.

Comment: i ment a single customized  gradle task that does  assembleDebug and assembleRelease or to use "gradlew assemble -x ..."